# extract numbers and alpha into two strings

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a string that looks like this `"dentist: 800-483-9767"` or this `"john (232)233-2323"` or some other combination that has numbers, letters and other types of characters, and that's max 25 characters long. I want to extract the digits and letters characters into 2 strings so that I get this:

```
string digits = "8004839767";
string letters = "dentist";
```

What's the best what to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Linq` and `char.IsDigit`, `char.IsLetter`

```
    string input = "dentist: 800-483-9767";

    string digits = new string(input.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    string letters = new string(input.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

Result:

```
input = "dentist: 800-483-9767";
digits = "8004839767"
letters = "dentist"

input = "john (232)233-2323";
digits = "2322332323"
letters = "john"
```

Answer (score 1):

If it really is about *getting digits and letters* (and not splitting somewhere, matching a phone number or someting similar), this would be my attempt:

```
var input = "dentist: 0800-483-9767";

var digits = string.Join(string.Empty, input.Where(char.IsDigit));
var letters = string.Join(string.Empty, input.Where(char.IsLetter));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string input = "dentist: 800-483-9767";

    string[] split = input.Split(':');

    string letters = split[0];

    string digits = split[1].Replace("-","").Trim();
```

Similar to what juergen d posted, however, it will remove the dashes in the number.

Answer (score 0):

When saying "looks like", you should be more specific about what can change and what cannot.

If the format is always :, you can do

```
Data process(String input)
{
    var elements = input.Split(new char[] {':'});
    Data result;
    result.letters = elements[0].Trim();
    result.digits = elements[1].Trim().Replace("-", "");
    return result;
}
```

---

That's *exactly* the kind of unprecision I was talking about.
If you are sure that the letters won't contain numbers, you can use a regular expression to separate the letters from the rest. If you are sure that the letters won't contain spaces, you can `Split(' ')`. I mean, could it be `john 2 232:233-2323`, where "john 2" is the name, and the rest is a number.

If you want to parse it, the first thing you have to do is to identify some kind of format.
If the name won't contain spaces, then just call `Split(' ', 2)`, take the first thing as the name, and remove everything that is not a number from the second one with a regular expression. I've never used regexp in C# before, but I think it should be `Regex.Replace(input, "[^\\d]+", "", RegexOptions.None)`.